# Disable line breaking after certain words

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, line-breaks

I have few UILabels in my app. All of them are set to be multiline by setting numberOfLines as 0. By this, some of them have 1 line, some have 2. My problem is, that according to grammar of language of this app, certain words should never be at the end of an line.

For example, let have sentence: "John is collecting fossils and stamps".

This line will be long enought for line breaking to appear after word "and". According to grammar, this should not happen, so I want to break line before this word, so instead of this after line break:

```
John is collecting fossils and
stamps
```

I want to get:

```
John is collecting fossils
and stamps
```

Is it possible to achieve this? I am working with iOS 7 and higher, so need not to care with compatibility with older iOS versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to make a subclass of UILabel with 2 methods. Lets assume, that I only want to disable line breaking after word "a" (similar solution can be with multiple words):

```
- (void)setText:(NSString*)newText {

    [super setText:[self fixSpaces:newText]];

}

- (NSString*)fixSpaces:(NSString*)originalText {

    NSMutableString* tempString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:originalText];
    [tempString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"a " withString:@"a " options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, tempString.length)];
    return tempString;

}
```

String that will be replaced is "a ", thats a standard 'a' and space. String that will replace it looks the same on the screen, but it is 'a' and non-breaking space (on MAC - Option + Space). Setting any text in a standard way of setting text to UILabel will always work as desired, but comparing string with text of label will not work (but it is easy to fix that by replacing non-breakable spaces with spaces for comparison). Setting text in storyboard or nib will naturally not work.